# How do I load a page from mysql database when clicked on link in a menu

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code from index.php

```
<?php
include("header.php"); 

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? trim(strtolower($_GET['page']))       : "home";

$allowedPages = array(
    'home'      => './home.php',
    'news'      => './news.php',
    'contact'   => './contact.php',
    'faq'       => './faq.php'
);

include( isset($allowedPages[$page]) ? $allowedPages[$page] : $allowedPages["home"] );

include("footer.php"); 
?>
```

At the moment working links open precreated pages (home.php, news.php, contactus.php, faq.php) from the root folder using hyperlinks like so:

```
<li><a href="index.php?page=home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=contact">Contact us</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?page=faq">FAQ</a></li>`
```

But the problem is that I want pages to be created dynamically according to data in mysql database.
I have a database called **aviumpages**
There's a table called **pages** inside.
There are columns called **id (INT)**, **linklabel (VARCHAR)**, **pagecontent (TEXT)** in the table.

I already inserted **linklabels** like *home, news, Contact Us* and *FAQ* accordingly. 
So how do I load a dynamically created page from database?

And I also have mysql_connect.php which is working.

Comment: You need to connect your database and make a query and print query values to webpage with php. Make some research before asking a question pls.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this by hand, you might be interested in [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/).  From the looks of your question you might want to look at:

1. <s>[W3Schools Primer on PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/)</s>
2. [Converting Static HTML Template to PHP](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/)
3. [PHP for the Absolute Beginner](http://devzone.zend.com/6/php-101-php-for-the-absolute-beginner/)

CakePHP integrates nicely with many templating engines, and has the integrated database connection you need to use, but before you jump into Cake, complete the Primer by hand.

Comment: @AlexMorrise Quote:
W3Schools still has issues but they have at least worked on the  primary concern developers had. For many beginners, W3Schools has  structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning  experience. However, it would be a mistake to continue your education without learning from more reputable sources, so when you're ready to level up, move on.
From the looks the OP isn't ready to move up yet...

Answer (score 0):

the rewrite is non-canned for intuitive flow

```
  include("header.php"); 

  if(!dbconnect($params)) {error(); exit;}
  $allowedPages = array(
      'home'      => './home.php',
      'news'      => './news.php',
      'contact'   => './contact.php',
      'faq'       => './faq.php'

  if(!isset($_GET['page'])||!array-key-exists(trim(strtolower($_GET['page'])),$allowedPages)){
    // fetch your home() data
    include($allowedPages['home'])
    }else{
    $page = trim(strtolower($_GET['page']));
    // fetch your $page() data // yeah, you can do that!
    include($allowedPages[$page]);
    }

  include("footer.php");
```

HTML

Home

News

Contact us

FAQ

`

~yeah, you can do that~

```
  function trythis(){
     echo "hello world";
     }

  $var = $_GET['var'];
  $var();
```

filename.php?var=trythis